# async Task Android Xamarin

Tags: android, asynchronous, xamarin, task

I am trying to load an image from a URL to later incorporate it into a list record. The problem is that it does not wait for the async task to finish. It executes the add but the image is null, because the async method is not finished.

How can I make it wait until the image is loaded and then add the record to the list?

```
private JavaList<Spacecraft> GetSpacecrafts()
{
    spacecrafts = new JavaList<Spacecraft>();
    Spacecraft s;
    foreach (DataRow row in tbs.Rows)
    {
        var t = Task.Run(() => CallMethod(row["nueve_seis"].ToString()));
        t.Wait();
        s = new Spacecraft(row["nombre"].ToString(),,row["uno_cutrocuatro"].ToString(), row["nombre"].ToString(), row["desc"].ToString(), row["urllocal"].ToString(), row["urlPublica"].ToString(), row["cuatro_ocho"].ToString(), row["siete_dos"].ToString(), row["nueve_seis"].ToString(), row["uno_cutrocuatro"].ToString(), row["uno_nuevedos"].ToString(), imageBitmap);
        spacecrafts.Add(s);
    }
    async void CallMethod(string nameimage)
    {
        await EjecutaTareaAsync(nameimage);
    }
    async Task EjecutaTareaAsync(string pathimg)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            imageBitmap = null;
            imageBitmap = GetImageBitmapFromUrl(pathimg);
        });
    }
    return spacecrafts;
}

private Bitmap GetImageBitmapFromUrl(string url)
{
    using (var webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        var imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData(url);
        if (imageBytes != null && imageBytes.Length > 0) return BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this code, it might help you

```
private async Task<Bitmap> GetImageBitmapFromUrl(string url)
{
    Uri param_url = new Uri(url);
    var webClient = new WebClient();
    var imageBytes = await webClient.DownloadDataTaskAsync(param_url);
    if (imageBytes != null && imageBytes.Length > 0) return BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
    return null;
}

void EjecutaTareaAsync(string pathimg)
{
    Task.Run(async() =>{ imageBitmap =await GetImageBitmapFromUrl(pathimg); }).Wait(); //this will wait until task completed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok lets start at the top. You want it to wait in the foreach when you CallMethod(...). So let's make the method an async method. Afterwards add await before the method call.

It was redundant the way you were setting up async/await calls. so I removed one of the methods and consolidated a bit.

https://blog.xamarin.com/getting-started-with-async-await/ a pretty good read and they talk about how to use async/await. it might be helpful.

```
private async JavaList<Spacecraft> GetSpacecrafts()
{
    spacecrafts = new JavaList<Spacecraft>();
    Spacecraft s;
    foreach (DataRow row in tbs.Rows)
    {
        var t = await CallMethod(row["nueve_seis"].ToString());
        s = new Spacecraft(row["nombre"].ToString(),,row["uno_cutrocuatro"].ToString(), row["nombre"].ToString(), row["desc"].ToString(), row["urllocal"].ToString(), row["urlPublica"].ToString(), row["cuatro_ocho"].ToString(), row["siete_dos"].ToString(), row["nueve_seis"].ToString(), row["uno_cutrocuatro"].ToString(), row["uno_nuevedos"].ToString(), imageBitmap);
        spacecrafts.Add(s);
    }
    return spacecrafts;
}

async Task CallMethod(string nameimage)
{
    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        imageBitmap = null;
        imageBitmap = GetImageBitmapFromUrl(pathimg);
    });
}

private Bitmap GetImageBitmapFromUrl(string url)
{
    using (var webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        var imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData(url);
        if (imageBytes != null && imageBytes.Length > 0) return BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
    }
    return null;
}
```